# Perfectly pixelmapped fonts in Emacs

Tags: x11, emacs, fonts

In Ubuntu, in IntelliJ, the font PragmataPro Mono looks like this:

[image]

Note the perfectly mapped pixels.  The IntelliJ setting `Appearance & Behavior > Appearance > Antialiasing > Editor` is set to `No antialiasing`.

In Emacs, the same font is antialiased:

[image]

If I add an `~/.Xresources` file containing `Emacs.font: PragmataPro Mono-12:antialias=false`, then Emacs looks like this:

[image]

The font is automatically bitmapped, but not according to the font's specification.

How can I replicate the IntelliJ's rendering in Emacs?

I have reproduced this issue in Ubuntu–Cinnamon and on Arch–Xfce. Thank you.

Comment: do the opposite https://askubuntu.com/questions/21097/configure-fontconfig-to-ignore-bitmaps-in-scalable-fonts

Answer (score 2):

If your problem with the anti aliased version of the rendering is, that the appearance is too thick, you can force a specific [font hinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting). I did it for the Lucida Console font in this way in my `~/.Xresources` file:

```
Emacs.font: Lucida Console-14:antialias=true:hinting=true:autohint=false:hintstyle=3
```

The available hint styles are:

```
hintnone        hintstyle       0
hintslight      hintstyle       1
hintmedium      hintstyle       2
hintfull        hintstyle       3
```

Comment: This is a decent workaround but it does not answer the question. I want to see pixelmappings that match the font's specification, as seen in the IntelliJ screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in `.Xresources` you need the following attributes:

```
Emacs.font: PragmataPro Mono-12:antialias=false:hinting=true:autohint=false
```

- font-size specified
- antialiasing needs to be off
- hinting needs to be true, but autohint needs to be off, otherwise automatic hinting will replace font-specified hinting.

Second of all, if you use `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Pragmata Pro Mono")` in Emacs, that will restore default hinting. You need to use the same syntax as in `.Xresources`:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil 
  :font "PragmataPro Mono-12:antialias=false:hinting=true:autohint=false")
```